# Arduino Turn Signals

Tags: power

Could I use an Arduino to power run the following lights? [Here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07Z5RGXJ8/ref=sspa_dk_detail_0?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B07Z5RGXJ8&pd_rd_w=vW0xN&pf_rd_p=1055d8b2-c10c-4d7d-b50d-96300553e15d&pd_rd_wg=dcoXb&pf_rd_r=SF8MZNZ4KBBW3GT7VYRD&pd_rd_r=746fc479-d3ba-4bd5-90ad-e842d645c150&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUE0RVdQSDNEWDRSTEQmZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTAxNDY0NzkyRUhINTNLMzVGNTlRJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA3MDM2OTkzQlNZRUs3NDFYUkFLJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfZGV0YWlsJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==) I have a project in mind, and although I am new to electronics, I am a computer programmer (C, C++, C#, Java) by profession so the coding side doesn't worry me, what I am confused about is what power supply I need etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to power it directly from a GPIO pin from an Arduino: no, for two reasons:

- It doesn't show the current needed, but it's likely more than 20 or 40 mA which is maximum for a GPIO pin. So you need to use a transistor, which can be used to turn on something with higher current, with the current of a GPIO pin. Search for 'Transistor as a switch' for more info.
- Also, it's 12 V and the Arduino delivers 5 V.

What you need is a separate 12V adapter, with a current capability MORE than what that light needs. I cannot find the current (mA) in the link, so you might need to measure it (e.g. with a digital multimeter). If you don't have a digital multimeter, buy one, you need one anyway if you will do electronics. You can even buy a 3 euro one from China if you want (for now).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the specs of those lights, they draw 1 watt at 12 volts. That is both too much current and too much voltage for an Arduino. (You're only supposed to draw about 20 mA from a single pin, and somewhere between 500 mA and 1 amp from the 5V regulator. (It is heat limited, and typically not very well heat-sinked. Er, heat-sunk?)

An Arduino only puts out 3.3v and 5V.

If you're looking to drive these from a car/motorcycle, you should be able to power them directly from the 12V battery of the vehicle. Failing that, get a 12V power supply that can put out as much current as you need for ALL of the lights you need, plus 10%-20% extra, for "slop".

What you should do is to buy a MOSFET power transistor designed for switching logic level signals for each turn signal you need to control. These would work well:
https://www.adafruit.com/product/355

You'd then use logic lines from the Arduino to control the gates of the transistors, and each transistor would switch the power for one of your turn signal lights.